# Dynamically check for field names in mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with a field defined as follows

```
    ActiveWeek: {type: String},
        Week1ScheduleEntries: [{
          PlayerName: String,
          Slots: { type: Array, default:[]}
        }],
        Week2ScheduleEntries: [{
          PlayerName: String,
          Slots: { type: Array, default:[]}
        }],
```

The active week will roll over every week on every Friday when the admin of my web app will hit a button. So if this week it is 1, the next week it will be 2

Is it possible in my backend node to check for this value 1 ,2 etc dynamically.
This is what i mean

Week(1,2,3...etc)ScheduleEntries

I dont know the right way to syntactically check this, if it is at all possible.

Comment: From what i understand, from your info, you can check the value by using find method.

Comment: no I want that value 1,2,3 etc to be dynamically checked...is there a way to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically checked? can you explain a little more ?

Comment: hi sajan, its a field in a mongoose schema. In my express route I am first receiving some entries coming from the front end and then after retrieving a record from my mongoose backend, I want to run a for loop over this array Week1ScheduleEntries. This  number 1 in the above field will change every week so in my code I want to check dynmically whats the value, is it 1, 2, 3, etc

Comment: so if the activeWeek is 1 then you need to loop through Week1ScheduleEntries and if activeWeek is 2 then you will loop through Week2ScheduleEntries.. Is this the behavior u are looking for ?

Comment: yes sir bang on.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try the below code

```
const selectedEntry = await schema.findOne(/* you filter */)
selectedEntry?.[`Week${selectedEntry.ActiveWeek}ScheduleEntries`]?.map(entry => {
    // you functions
});
```

This will get your job done.